# Scala regex on a whole column

Tags: regex, scala

I have the following pattern that I could parse using pandas in Python, but struggle with translating the code into Scala.

```
grade string_column    
 85   (str:ann smith,14)(str:frank chase,15)
 86   (str:john foo,15)(str:al more,14)
```

In python I used:

```
df.set_index('grade')['string_column']\
.str.extractall(r'\((str:[^,]+),(\d+)\)')\
.droplevel(1)
```

with the output:

```
 grade       0                1
 85      str:ann smith       14
 85      str:frank chase     15
 86      str:john foo        15
 86      str:al more         14
```

In Scala I tried to duplicate the approach, but it's failing:

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex

val pattern = new Regex("((str:[^,]+),(\d+)\)")
val str = "(str:ann smith,14)(str:frank chase,15)"

println(pattern findAllIn(str)).mkString(","))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few notes about the code:

- There is an unmatched parenthesis for a group, but that one should be escaped
- The backslashes should be double escaped
- In the `println` you don't have to use all the parenthesis and the dot
- [findAllIn](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/util/matching/Regex.html#findAllIn(source:CharSequence):scala.util.matching.Regex.MatchIterator) returns a MatchIterator, and looping those will expose a matched string. Joining those matched strings with a comma, will in this case give back the same string again.

For example

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex

val pattern = new Regex("\\((str:[^,]+),(\\d+)\\)")
val str = "(str:ann smith,14)(str:frank chase,15)"

println(pattern findAllIn str mkString ",")
```

Output

```
(str:ann smith,14),(str:frank chase,15)
```

But if you want to print out the group 1 and group 2 values, you can use [findAllMatchIn](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/util/matching/Regex.html#findAllMatchIn(source:CharSequence):Iterator%5Bscala.util.matching.Regex.Match%5D) that returns a collection of Regex Matches:

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex

val pattern = new Regex("\\((str:[^,]+),(\\d+)\\)")
val str = "(str:ann smith,14)(str:frank chase,15)"
pattern findAllMatchIn str foreach(m => {
    println(m.group(1))
    println(m.group(2))
  }
)
```

Output

```
str:ann smith
14
str:frank chase
15
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, `Series.str.extractall` only returns captured substrings. In Scala, `findAllIn` returns the matched values if you do not query its `matchData` property that in its turn contains a `subgroups` property.

So, to get the captures only in Scala, you need to use

```scala
val pattern = """\((str:[^,()]+),(\d+)\)""".r
val str = "(str:ann smith,14)(str:frank chase,15)"
(pattern findAllIn str).matchData foreach {
    m => println(m.subgroups.mkString(","))
}
```

Output:

```
str:ann smith,14
str:frank chase,15
```

See the [Scala online demo](https://ideone.com/gnu5f5).

Here, `m.subgroups` accesses all subgroups (captures) of each match (`m`).

Also, note you do not need to double backslashes in triple-quoted string literals. `\((str:[^,()]+),(\d+)\)` matches

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(str:[^,()]+)` - Group 1: `str:` and one or more chars other than `,`, `(` and `)`
- `,` - a comma
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `\)` - a `)` char.

If you just want to get all matches without captures, you can use

```scala
val pattern = """\((str:[^,]+),(\d+)\)""".r
println((pattern findAllIn str).matchData.mkString(","))
```

Output:

```
(str:ann smith,14),(str:frank chase,15)
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/O4FVmo).

Comment: thank you. How do I need to adjust the code to get the output in a new dataframe like in pandas?